# Angular2, Primeng 4.1.1 data table performance is very slow in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, primeng, primeng-datatable

I developed a simple .netc ore spa app using angular2 and primeng 4.1.1  controls, my app works fine in chrome  but when it comes to IE11, it is taking 8 seconds to load 120 records, I tried removing all the filters in data table, and just loaded table with plain json respose but it is still very slow, it works good only up to 10 records.
Right now if I can't fix this performance issue  in IE11, my app is use less, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything in the console?  or Extraneous calls being made in the network tab?  Without a reproducible example I'm not sure how much help you can get.

Comment: There are only 4 get calls, these are internal, it takes overall  4s in IE, and 2s in chrome. only issue with IE,  it is taking more time to render data table after the response

Comment: Are you using dataKey attribute for p-datatable? If not then add it with unique column name i.e. dataKey="vin" where vin is the unique key column.

Comment: I have used dataKey as well but there is no performance improvement

Comment: You should share your code, so we can see if there is anything to be optimized. Also, you can try new primeng table (TurboTable) which is said to be 10x times faster than the current one. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table